# Processing function in Yii2 Kartik GridView property

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

In my Kartik GridView viewfile, I am attempting to process a function for the `detailRowCssClass` property of an ExpandRowColumn. Regardless of setup, (such as applying an empty function or returning direct strings), the result is always the same and an object is returned.

```
'detailRowCssClass' => function($data){
    if($data->status == 0)
    {
        return GridView::TYPE_INFO;
    }
    elseif($data->status == 1)
    {
        return GridView::TYPE_WARNING;
    }
    elseif($data->status == 2)
    {
        return GridView::TYPE_SUCCESS;
    }
},
```

returns a class of `[object Object]`

Does anyone know a workaround, or what I am fundamentally missing in that this does not return a string? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that *detailRowCssClass* of the class *kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn* is a **simple string** and not a closure. The appropriate parts from the source file `vendor/kartik-v/yii2-grid/src/ExpandRowColumn.php`:

```
class ExpandRowColumn extends DataColumn
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var string the CSS class for the detail content table row.
     */
    public $detailRowCssClass;
    ...
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @throws InvalidConfigException
     */
    public function init()
    {
        if (!isset($this->detailRowCssClass)) {
            $this->detailRowCssClass = $this->grid->getCssClass(GridView::BS_TABLE_INFO);
        }
    ...
        $clientOptions = Json::encode(
            [
                'gridId' => $this->grid->options['id'],
                'hiddenFromExport' => $this->hiddenFromExport,
                'detailUrl' => empty($this->detailUrl) ? '' : $this->detailUrl,
                'onDetailLoaded' => $onDetailLoaded,
                'expandIcon' => $this->expandIcon,
                'collapseIcon' => $this->collapseIcon,
                'expandTitle' => $this->expandTitle,
                'collapseTitle' => $this->collapseTitle,
                'expandAllTitle' => $this->expandAllTitle,
                'collapseAllTitle' => $this->collapseAllTitle,
                'rowCssClass' => $this->detailRowCssClass,
                'animationDuration' => $this->detailAnimationDuration,
                'expandOneOnly' => $this->expandOneOnly,
                'enableRowClick' => $this->enableRowClick,
                'enableCache' => $this->enableCache,
                'rowClickExcludedTags' => array_map('strtoupper', $this->rowClickExcludedTags),
                'collapseAll' => false,
                'expandAll' => false,
                'extraData' => $this->extraData,
            ]
        );
    ...
    }
```